# How to get/set the Title of a button after that was passed into UIBarButtonItem-customView constructor

Tags: swift3, uibarbuttonitem

When I create a UIBarButtonItem with the **customView** constructor, that gets a UIButton with specific properties set, how can I access that properties after the UIBarButtonItem object was created?

```
var uiBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "image-name"), for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("My Button Title", for: .normal)
    button.sizeToFit()
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(aFuncName), for: .touchUpInside)
    return UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
}
```

It should work like the following pseudo code:

```
uiBarButtonItem.button.titleLabel.text
// should return "My Button Title"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the customView property of your `UIBarButtonItem`.

```
if let barItem = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem, //Access rightBarButtonItem if you have set right item
   let btn = barItem.customView as? UIButton {

    btn.setTitle("New", for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: @F.Schmidt Welcome mate :)